# Html to PDF and security

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a web app that is using forms security.

One of the options includes the ability to print an html page to PDF.  We're currently evaluating different products like [PdfMetamorphosis](http://www.sautinsoft.com/products/pdf-metamorphosis/index.php), but I believe all of them will have this issue.

The client makes a request for the pdf by clicking a link button.  The code for the button instantiates the PDF builder and passes it a url to convert.  However, the URL is behind our forms authentication.  Which means that the resulting PDF is nothing but a login page.

Unfortunately, we need the user information in order to verify acccess to the printed page (among other reasons).  Which means I can't just allow access to everyone to that folder.

So I need one of three possible solutions.

1) I need a way to give the PdfMetamorphosis component the authorization ticket to pass on in it's request.
2) I need an html to pdf component that will do this.
3) Something else?

I don't think the first one is possible and I haven't been able to find a html to pdf component that takes this into consideration.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you check their permission before they click print, why show them a print to PDF button if they don't have permission.  If this is not possible, can you replace the print to PDF button to first show a modal dialog box if they don't have a access token, then forward on their request if they have permission.

Comment: @Zack:  The problem is that the component which runs on the server is making a request to the html file.  When it makes this request, the server is checking the security again.  I can't see how to pass on the security credentials for that request.  Make sense?

Comment: Can't you pass login information in the url passed to the builder? That means your forms auth page would need to support that, of course

Comment: @Simon: I believe forms auth uses a security token in a cookie.  I can't pass that cookie along using this html-pdf toolkit.

Comment: Well, if the PDF builder is properly written, it can perfectly support this. And if it doesn't, couldn't you write a frontend to it that will load the url as a file and pass it to?

Comment: @Simon: Well that's certainly a good idea.  The toolkit does support just passing the html into it as a string.  Add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to pass login information in the url passed to the builder. That means your forms auth page would need to support that, of course.

Now, since the Forms Auth login probably uses cookies, you will have to check the PDF Builder supports cookies when it gets the document from the url.

If it doesn't, then you'll have to write some kind of frontend class that will load the document from the url, supporting Forms Auth cookies, and passes it as a file or a stream to the PDF Builder for final processing.

Comment: gracias.  My brain apparently didn't come to work with me today.  I hope to catch back up with it later for dinner.